# should I learn oracle 10g or 11g ?Is oracle 10g outdated now?

Tags: oracle

I am engineering student.

Should I learn oracle 10g or oracle 11g now for getting a certification after 1 year?

Is oracle 10g outdated now?

Comment: Actually this isn't really a question for stackoverflow, but anyway: from a beginner's point of view there isn't much of a difference between these two versions. But If you go for a certificate I would opt for an 11g certificate. 10g _certificates_ might be outdated, _knowledge_ about 10g definitely not.

Comment: "10g certificates might be outdated, knowledge about 10g definitely not" .. So true...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to strengthen RDBMS concepts rather than concentrating on "whether 10g or 11g?" These version of databases are best learnt in a large scale enterprise environment (which you would get an opportunity to, in near future), and RDBMS knowledge will help you in every step be it 10g or 11g or any future versions.